# PyQt4 pyuic4 spacerItem as a member of class

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyuic

I have no idea how to force pyuic4 to generate QSpacerItem's as a class members in a .py file. Everything else is generate as a members of a class, for example gridLayout

```
self.gridLay = QtGui.QGridLayout()
```

Everything except QSpacerItem

```
spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 0, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
self.gridLay.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 2, 1, 1)
```

Any idea how to correct that?

PS I don't ask how to correct it manually ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing you can do to change this behaviour through the `pyuic4` interface.

However, `pyuic4` is written in PyQt, so if you feel like hacking, the relevant code is in `PyQt4/uic/uiparser.py`. Specifically, the `createSpacer` and `setupObject` methods of the `UIParser` class. The `setupObject` method is what is normally used to create attributes for objects, but obviously the `createSpacer` method doesn't currently use it.

I'm not sure why things are currently done this way. To get a definitive answer, you'd probably have to ask the project maintainer (Phil Thompson) on the [PyQt Mailing List](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt).

Also note that, if you know the spacer's position in the grid-layout, you can access it like this:

```
self.gridLay.itemAtPosition(row, column).spacerItem()
```

Answer (score 1):

Pyuic4 is a thin wrapper on top of the Qt `uic` utility, which has very few options, and this is way beyond its abilities.

What you can do is, in the customary subclass, to save a reference to that item (you've designed the thing, so you're supposed to know on which row/column the spacer is):

```
# somewhere in your __init__(), *after* calling super()
self.spacerItem = self.gridLay.itemAtPosition ( row, column )
```

You really should subclass anything coming out of pyuic anyway, so this shouldn't be a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

With your advices I found the solution. I modify PyQt4/uic/uiparser.py a little bit.

```
361     def createSpacer(self, elem):
362         name = elem.attrib.get('name') #get the name
363         width = elem.findtext("property/size/width")
364         height = elem.findtext("property/size/height")
365         
366         if width is None or height is None:
367             size_args = ()
368         else:
369             size_args = (int(width), int(height))
370             
371         sizeType = self.wprops.getProperty(elem, "sizeType",
372                 QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
373                 
374         policy = (QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, sizeType)
375         
376         if self.wprops.getProperty(elem, "orientation") == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
377             policy = policy[1], policy[0]
378             
379         spacer = self.factory.createQObject("QSpacerItem",
380                 self.uniqueName(name), size_args + policy,
381                 is_attribute=True) #is_attribute=True + set name
382                 
383         if self.stack.topIsLayout():
384             lay = self.stack.peek()
385             gp = elem.attrib["grid-position"]
386             
387             if isinstance(lay, QtGui.QFormLayout):
388                 lay.setItem(gp[0], self._form_layout_role(gp), spacer)
389             else:
390                 lay.addItem(spacer, *gp)
```

Thanks for help!